# truffle migration error

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, dapp-debugging

this is the truffle-config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    development: {
      network_id: "*",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545, // for ganache gui
      //port: 8545, // for ganache-cli
      gas: 6721975,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
    },
  },
};
```

I keep getting the following error when I run truffle migrate:

```
Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network at http://localhost:7545. Check your network configuration.
CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:7545.
```

Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v18.16.1

Comment: Is the development network running? The command is `truffle develop` in a separate terminal.